# How to specify a controller method will ONLY return jSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller method that will return just JSON. It will never be rendered in HTML ever. I know I can call controllerMethod.json?params=BLAHBLAH and it will return JSON for me, but if someone calls controllerMethod?params=BLAH I always want to return JSON as well... How do I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056293/respond-to-only-format-js-for-all-mime-types/7056325#7056325

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just do only:

```
respond_to :json
```